# Radio Button Struts 1.3

Tags: java, struts

I would like to create a radio button to select the values displayed on a jsp page.
how can I use radio buttons  to select values from this JSP page ?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%! int i=0; %>

<h1 align="center">DOCUMENT INFORMATION CENTER</h1> 
<table border="12" align="center">

<tr><td>Employee ID</td><td>Document ID</td><td>Topic</td><td>Text</td><td>Files</td></tr>
<% int j=(Integer)session.getAttribute("i");
HttpSession session2=request.getSession();
for(i=0;i<j;i++)
{ out.println("<tr><td>"+session.getAttribute("eid"+i)+"</td><td>"+session2.getAttribute("id"+i)+"</td><td>"+session2.getAttribute("topic"+i)+"</td><td>"+session2.getAttribute("text"+i)+"</td><td>"+session2.getAttribute("files"+i)+"</td></tr>");
}

%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _Which values_ do you want to select?

Comment: the values of the session object inside the out.println

Answer (score 0):

You can use struts logic tags for this purpose. If the session logic present set the value of particular radio button as true. For iterating purpose also you can use logic:iterate tag. Following piece of code may help you.

```
<logic:present name="i" scope="session">
<logic:equal value="1" name="i" scope="session">
    <script>
        $('input[name=some_name][value=1]').prop("checked",true);
    </script>
</logic:equal>
</logic:present>
```

Let me know if this helps..